# Save out Backup Database to local file

Tags: database

I've inherited a Craft 2 site to do maintenance. I don't yet have access to production server. I need to grab the production server DB to run locally on my machine. When I click "Backup Database" from the sites cms back-end, it doesn't appear to download a local `.sql` file. I assume it's backing up as a file on the actual server. How can I download that backup locally?

Comment: If you're in the Craft 2 control panel, and you click on *Backup Database*, it should always store an sql file in `craft/storage/backups`. If you have the *Download Backup* box checked, then also your browser should download a .zip file containing that .sql file.

Comment: @kr37 sounds like that makes a solid answer instead of a comment to me. :) care to add it as one?

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the Craft 2 control panel, and you click on *Backup Database*, it should always store a .sql file in `craft/storage/backups`.

If you have the *Download Backup* box checked, then also your browser should download a .zip file containing that .sql file.

Other notes:
It appears to work the same in Craft 3
If you do *Clear Caches* first, you may get a significantly smaller file.